# Windows service with WCF named pipes does not work without WCF Services Host

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, service

I am making Windows service in C# with named pipes partially according  [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx), but instead WCF TCP I am using named pipes. I use .NET framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2013 and OS MS Windows 8.1 x64. All works ok when I use WCF Services Host. But I need comunnicate with my installed Windows service directly. If I turn off WCF Services Host in WCF project properties I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException occurred in mscorlib.dll
>        Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/Service5 that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.

App.config of WindowsService and WcfService projects are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary5.Service5">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary5.IService5">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Service5" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

App.config of TestClient is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService5" />
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Service5" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService5" contract="ServiceReference1.IService5"
                name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService5">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Where is the problem please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Both your service and your client are configured to use WCF, so the WCF services host needs to be running.  Using native named pipes is completely different, it simply doesn't make sense to start from a WCF example if you don't want to use WCF.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for reply, Have you any other example for making Windows Service with communication via named pipes please?